# What is better, installing Win8 on an SSD directly or using the SSD for ReadyBoost?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, readyboost

For a medium SSD and a large HD, which scenario has a better performance-to-annoyance ratio?

- Install Windows on my HD and use [ReadyBoost](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff356869.aspx) to cache the hottest 32GB of files from my HD. Install some programs manually on the SSD to use all it's speed.
- Install Windows on my SSD and install some programs manually on the HD when I'm concerned about space.

Let's say 90GB SSD and 1TB HD if you want to put solid numbers to it. I want to make this question applicable to more people than my specific hard drive sizes though.

Comment: How much system memory do you have? Based on my **personal** experience its very possible that, Windows will refuse to use ReadyBoost, past a certain memory threshold. Your second choice will bring the best performance increases with Windows 8.  **Its also very likely Windows will refuse to use the SSD as a Readyboost device.**

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend installing the OS on the SSD.  The biggest benefit you'll notice are faster boot times.  ReadyBoost provides some of the performance improvements, but it won't be across the board like the full OS would.